# What is the Swift equivalent of UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to detect when a pan gesture ends.  Under Objective-C, I would do something like the following:

```
- (void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In my Swift project, it doesn't recognize `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`... Maybe I just need to import something different(?)

Comment: You may want to get familiar with reading the documentation...... option clicking UIGesterRecognizerStateEnded or searching the documentation will show you the Swift documentation as well.

Comment: @TheCoding Art - actually option clicking UIGesterRecognizerStateEnded does not show the Swift documentation because as the OP states a Swift project does not recognise it.

Comment: It recognizes it, and you can always open up the document manually and search for UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded. It'll then show the obj c and swift implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The equivalent is just

```
gesture.state == .Ended
```

or if you like

```
gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
```